# Can't insert img tag after adding custom plugin for image

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I have written my own custom plugin for inserting images in CKEDITOR. I disable the image button in toolbar . I use the editor.insertHtml() function to insert the image from my custom plugin . When I remove the standard image button from the toolset it disables insertion of image tag in the CKEDITOR box . All other html tags are accepted but for the `<img/>` tag .

This is my config(without the 'Image' in config.toolbar) :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('insert_blank','http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/plugins/insert_blank/', 'plugin.js');
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('qimage','http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/plugins/qimage/', 'plugin.js');
 config.extraPlugins = 'insert_blank,qimage' ; 

  config.toolbar =
    [

        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','-','Italic' ] },

        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'insert_blank.btn','-','qimage.btn'
                 ] },




    ];
   config.keystrokes = [

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 75, 'InsertBlank' ],    
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85, 'qimage' ], 
];  

        config.height = 300 ; 
                config.width = 350 ; 
                config.removePlugins =  'elementspath,resize' ;

};
```

Is there a way to enable image tag insert ?

**UPDATE** : Worked by adding the following command to the config file :

```
config.allowedContent = 'b i img[!src,alt,width,height]' ;
```

Comment: You don't need to allow for `p`. It is automatically registered based on current `config.enterMode` setting.

Comment: Technical note: If you solve your problem/question yourself, please, always form a full answer to your question with it, not an edit to the question itself. Edits are for clarification about question, not for answering. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read how to integrate plugin with [Allowed Filter Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf)? You need to define that your plugin adds button/command which allow `img` tag and its attributes. You can also define which tag and its attributes are definitely required for this button/command to be enabled, what will activate/deactivate it when someone will set `config.allowedContent`.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is just to enable the `img[src]` attribute.

So you should use `config.extraAllowedContent = 'img[src,alt,width,height]';`

the `config.allowedContent` will override all the others DOMs.