# insertHTML in CKEditor does not works only for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have tried to insert an uploaded image in to the CKEditor by using the following code,

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.writearticle;
var value = '<img src="images/imagename.jpg">';
editor.insertHtml( value );
```

But this does not work. But when I try the same logic with this code

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.writearticle;
var value = '<strong>Hello World</strong>';
editor.insertHtml( value );
```

**Hello world** as bold text is inserted. Why it is not working for the `<img>` tag?

I have found this procedure [here](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/api.html) and `<img>` insertion works in this site. What is the problem in my site?

Comment: Can Image tag be seen on html page? If yes Check if your image path is correct.

Comment: @Nitinvarpe: No the `<img>` is not getting inserted. But for other tags such as `<strong>`, `<p>` get inserted properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483344/ckeditor-image-insert-disabled-on-adding-custom-plugin-for-image check this link

Comment: Oh Man!! No words to express my thanks :)

Comment: u r welcome, My pleasure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved after adding,

```
config.allowedContent = 'img[src,alt,width,height]'; // But be sure to add all the other tags you use in with your Editor. Tags except this will be disabled.
```

Alternate solution

`config.extraAllowedContent = 'img[src,alt,width,height]'`

This will add `<img>` attribute to the allowed tags list and here you need to to specify every tags you need to allow. - **Credit: [Sibbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701563/sibbl)**.

in the config.js file.

Comment: If you don't want to list all other tags so that they will not be disabled, simply use `config.extraAllowedContent = 'img[src,alt,width,height]';`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just added:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

in the CKEditor configuration

and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write allowedContent in here instead modify the config.

```
editor.addCommand( 'XXXDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'XXXDialog', { allowedContent : 'img[src,alt,width,height]'}) );
```